# Invalid timestamp when reading Elasticsearch records with Spark

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-hadoop

I'm getting invalid timestamp when reading Elasticsearch records using Spark with elasticsearch-hadoop library. I'm using following Spark code for records reading:

```scala
val sc = spark.sqlContext
  val elasticFields = Seq(
    "start_time",
    "action",
    "category",
    "attack_category"
  )

  sc.sql(
    "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE myIndex " +
      "USING org.elasticsearch.spark.sql " +
      "OPTIONS (resource 'aggattack-2021.01')" )

  val all = sc.sql(
    s"""
      |SELECT ${elasticFields.mkString(",")}
      |FROM myIndex
      |""".stripMargin)
  all.show(2)
```

Which leads to the following result:

```
+-----------------------+------+---------+---------------+
|start_time             |action|category |attack_category|
+-----------------------+------+---------+---------------+
|1970-01-19 16:04:27.228|drop  |udp-flood|DoS            |
|1970-01-19 16:04:24.027|drop  |others   |DoS            |
+-----------------------+------+---------+---------------+
```

But I'm expecting timestamp with current year, eg `2021-01-19 16:04:27.228`. In the elastic, `start_time` field has unixtime format in millis -> `start_time": 1611314773.641`

Comment: Try to read as string and cast it to timestamp in Spark. Add this in options : `OPTIONS('resource'='aggattack-2021.01', 'es.mapping.date.rich'= 'false')` then cast using : `from_unixtime(start_time) as start_time`

Comment: Hi, I tried it, but it leads to another exception => `The value (1609467228) of the type (java.lang.Long) cannot be converted to the string type`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with the data in ElasticSearch. `start_time` field was mapped as `epoch_seconds` and contained value epoch seconds with three decimal places (eg `1611583978.684`). Everything works fine after we have converted epoch time to millis without any decimal places